# How can you disable the V/InstrumentationResultParser output when running Instrumentation Tests

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3.2.1/`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`, and noticed that when I run Instrumentation Tests there is a lot of new output that clogs up the logs I like to view.  Here's a small preview:

`07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.zach.testapp.ExampleInstrumentedTest
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=AndroidJUnitRunner
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=useAppContext
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
07:38:28 V/InstrumentationResultParser: INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream=`

For a new project with a single Instrumentation test, over 50 lines of text are displayed as output.  In my 'main' project I have several hundred Instrumentation tests, and this makes the output very difficult to read for meaningful information (like failures) because I have to scroll so much.

Is there a way to disable this logging?

Comment: Any new ideas with this? I have to say this really makes finding the failing tests in Jenkins outputs hard. Also since there is a total lack of posts about this I think this is unwanted behaviour and doesn't happen to a lot of people.

Comment: We feel your pain. More than 1000 hits for InstrumentationResultParser in one of my jenkins logs. Alot of times whatever the native build system emits cannot be changed without going through major hoops like writing your own parser, outputting to a separate file, etc. For android we should be able to get the junit.xml summaries though.

Comment: I have created an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124025083. At this point we are parsing the output. However, certain outputs may still get overlooked with this. I hope this gets changed soon or at least gets an option for disabling the outputs.

Comment: Any progress on this? Currently the issue tracker shows me a message 'Access denied for: <my-google-account>' when I click on the link.

Comment: I get the same message. It seems like they've just deleted the issue or restricted access to it wihout any notice. Very odd. Looks like for now we have to make-do with console parsing plugins for jenkins.

Comment: Funny, I actually wanted these logs, but they seem to have been removed during the upgrade from AGP 3.5 to 3.6. The above issue on the Google issue tracker is not accessible (even when signed in): Access denied :(